# Can xlsxwriter draw waterfall graphs?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I want to draw a waterfall chart by using xlsxwriter. I have read the chart documents https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-class but cannot find any information about it.

Is it possible to draw a 'Waterfall' chart in xlsxwriter just as the one in excel? One step further, is the horizontal bar waterfall available as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Waterfall charts aren’t supported in XlsxWriter since they are a, relatively, recent addition to Excel.